# Ошибка при создании базы

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Класс контроллера:**

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        IShopRepository shop;
       
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger , IShopRepository shopcont )
        {
           
            this.shop = shopcont;
            
                _logger = logger;
        }
```

**ShopContext:**

```
 public class ShopContext : DbContext
    {

            
        public ShopContext(DbContextOptions<ShopContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        
    }
```

**ShopInject:**

```
 public interface IShopRepository
    {
       ///код
    }

    public class ShopInject :  IShopRepository
    {
        ShopContext shop;
        
        public ShopInject(ShopContext shopcont)
        {
            this.shop = shopcont;
          
        }
      
    }
```

**ConfigureServices:**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<ShopContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(connection, builder =>
       {
           builder.EnableRetryOnFailure();
       }));
           
            services.AddSingleton<IShopRepository, ShopInject>();
          
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddReact();
            services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName = ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName).AddChakraCore();
        }
```

При запуске приложения получаю **ошибку:**

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Shop.Models.ShopContext' from singleton 'Shop.Containers.IShopRepository.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Спасибо, я заменил

```
services.AddSingleton<IShopRepository, ShopInject>();
```

на

```
services.AddTransient<IShopRepository, ShopInject>();
```

И ошибка ушла . Но дальше я  добавил  такие строчки для заполнения базы:

```
   public ShopInject(ShopContext shopcont)
        {
            this.shop = shopcont;
           
            
            if (!this.shop.Products.Any())
            {



                this.shop.Products.AddRange(
                new Product
                {
                    Count = 20,
                    Name = "Спрайт",
                    Price = 15,
                    Image = "/images/Спрайт.png"
                }
               
               
              
                );

                this.shop.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
```

И при создании базы добавляемая строка дублируется. Не подскажете с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45811225/12888024), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57582246/12888024) как-то так

Comment: [Captive dependency](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines)